# How to store the result of running a for loop in different files?

Tags: python, c++, c

I have a main.cc file which I run using different command line argument(one of them is h). I have to assign different values to h. I want to run main.cc file using a for loop picking a different value of h ranging [0.2,0.8,1.5]?. Given h=0.2, I want a new file named "file_h=0.2" with the results in that file. Can I run this main.cc file using a script of python and then store the result of each loop in a different file?

```
#include "Models.h"
#include "L.h"
#include "o.h"
#command line arguments:
int _seed = 1234567; 
double _h = 1.0; 
int _nS = 1; 
int _if = 3; 


int init(int argc, char* argv[]) {

int c, errflg = 0;
    while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "d:f:hn:s:t:x:w:z:")) != EOF)
    switch(c) {
case 'f':
    _if = atoi(optarg);
break
case 'h':
    _h = atof(optarg);
break;
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to write a loop in C?

Comment: Note that your match string contains `hn` ... while switch look for `h`

Comment: I have edited my question. main.cc file is written such that it picks a single value of h. Should I use for loop to change the value of h? Can I load this main.cc file on new file and then run for loop on new file?

Comment: This can be solved with a short bash script: `for h in 0.2 0.8 1.5; do ./a.out -h $h; done`

Comment: Fllow this example: https://coderwall.com/p/y3xnxg/using-getopt-vs-boost-in-c-to-handle-arguments

Comment: If you don't want to use a script to run it, why not move all the values of `h` into an array and then loop over the array. In this case, the `h` is not coming from command line anymore

Comment: @MohammadAKanan: In both C and C++, strings cannot be used to name compile-time variables. In reality, `hn:` refers to the command line options `-h` and `-n ARG`

Comment: I want to write for loop in the new script so that I don't need to adjust spacing of whole code. But then Im confused that can I load this main.cc file one new.cc file?Is it a correct way

Comment: I see you don't want to change `main.cc`, but you still want to test different values of `h`. Instead of writing a new file called `new.cc`, you should use the bash script idea I suggested. Does this work for you?

Comment: Yes you got it. Actually I'm not familiar with bash.If possible I want to implement for loop in "new.cc". Can we da that? Is it a correct day? I'm a newbie in  C++. Just few days ago I started working on it

Comment: First I want using "make "which compiles main.cc file(which is taking one value of h). It seems to me that I need to apply for loop in main.cc. I'm looking for other way so I don't need to modify main.cc

Comment: You can do it in C++, but because C++ is not primarily a scripting language, you will have get into the murky details of spawning a new process which will call `make`, then after that process is finished, you spawn more processes in a loop to run your executable with the arguments. Spawning processes in C++ is also platform dependent, so you need to know the platform well enough to do that.  This is why I suggest a scripting language. Since you are not familiar with shell scripting, maybe python?

Comment: No I'm not familiar with shell script. Can I infer from your comment that for loop inside main.cc is the only option?

Comment: I also suggested python but yea a for loop inside `main.cc` is the easiest option

Comment: In python I know how to load a file using os.sys("main.cc")

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199593/discussion-between-smac89-and-jerry).